# Is there a way to get data from a string and map it to a 3D array in C#?

Tags: c#, string, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a script that reads an input .txt file that stores a 3D(?) matrix on each line (each line is a different matrix), I have managed to cut the file's lines into separate strings, now I have to read one of the strings (the first line's), which is just a long line of square brackets, commas, and numbers.

```
//example
[[[[1, []], [6, [1, 2, 11]], [0, [11]]], [[0, [2]], [0, [2]], [0, [11]]], [[0, [1]], [6, []], [0, [11]]]], [[[0, []], [0, []], [0, [11]]], [[0, []], [0, []], [0, [11]]], [[0, [2]], [0, [1,2]], [0, [11]]]], [[[0, [2]], [6, [11]], [0, [11]]], [[0, [6, 4]], [0, []], [0, [11]]], [[0, [1, 2]], [6, []], [0, [2, 11]]]]]
```

> 3 columns, 3 rows, and 3 "layers" (there are always 3 layers, but the amount of columns and rows will be different for each file's first line matrix)
>
> the matrix starts from the top left (1x, 1y, 1z) and goes through each 'dimension' backwards (e.g. x1 y1 z1 -> x1 y1 z2 -> x1 y1 z3 -> x1 y2 z1 -> x1 y2 z2, etc),
>
> each cell of the matrix looks like [int, [<comma separated list of ints, nothing if there's no ints>]]

The example above is relatively small compared to some of the other files' first line matrices (the average size of the matrices is 72 x 43 x 3).

And because the matrix's size varies between files, I cannot brute force it.

I can read the matrices by hand, but I have no idea how to tell C# how to read the matrices.
I am not very skilled in C# (or coding in general) so I do not know where to start.

Comment: You'll have to write code to parse this. That's not a 3D array. That's a completely custom representation that may or may not represent the values of an array with 3 dimensions.

Comment: This string could be parsed as a JSON array, but making sense of this is another matter. You'd end up with multiple nested arrays

Comment: what could I use to parse the string with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed around with something called Regex and was able to get (at least in substring form) all the parts I wanted with this:

```
/\[[0-9]+,\s\[([0-9]*,?\s*[0-9]*)*\]{1,2}/gi
```

I probably could have used some kind of JSON array thingamajig,  but that would have taken wayyyy too long for me to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply fetch the txt string of the matrix and then de-serialize this test to get your 3d matrix. Sample:

```
var txtString = "[[[[1, []], [6, [1, 2, 11]], [0, [11]]], [[0, [2]], [0, [2]], [0, [11]]], [[0, [1]], [6, []], [0, [11]]]], [[[0, []], [0, []], [0, [11]]], [[0, []], [0, []], [0, [11]]], [[0, [2]], [0, [1,2]], [0, [11]]]], [[[0, [2]], [6, [11]], [0, [11]]], [[0, [6, 4]], [0, []], [0, [11]]], [[0, [1, 2]], [6, []], [0, [2, 11]]]]]";
var matrix = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(txtString);
```

Comment: `var matrix = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[][][]>(txtString);` might be wiser

Comment: Agreed, defining the data type is always wiser.

Comment: I am not dealing with JSON though

Comment: Just to get a 3d matrix (any data type as you wish) from  a text string, JSON de-serialize is what I recommend.